# Python logging using modules

Tags: python, logging, module

I have multiple modules, which are called by a principal script. Each one does log messages using logging Python builtin package.

**How can I log an session ID, set during the execution of the main script, across all modules, without needing to push this variable in each module?**

I have set up a python configuration file, called config, with:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format="%(filename)s:%(lineno)s|%(funcName)3s()|%(asctime)s|%(levelname)s|%(message)s",
    handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler("debug.log"),
        logging.StreamHandler()
    ]
)
```

Other modules are using this pre configured logging object, via import, so I am using this:

```
from config import logging
```

But I need to log an ID from my current session, my log should look like:

> module_name.py:25|function_name()|2020-04-27 18:28:26,518|INFO|**Session_ID=abc123**|some_message_here

I have tried to put this variable in the config file, set it, and then use it in a function named "log_info" and "log_debug" in this file, but my output log does not trace python script name and function name any more.

Does anyone knows how to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the 100% best solution, or for sure if it'll work in your situation, but I used it for something similar (verbosity printing levels that would persist across several scripts).

Create a Python file, named, say, `sessionid`. Inside that, define a top-level setting named `id`. To set your id, `import sessionid` and `sessionid.id = 'some_id'`. Then have your `config` file import `sessionid` as well and use `sessionid.id` as needed.

It took me a bit to figure out that I had to access it like that; changing it using `from sessionid import id; id = 'some_id'` only persists within the script that does so.

It would make sense to put the `id` variable in your `config` file, but only if you don't need to set it in the same script that also needs to `from config import logging`.

Comment: Hi @CrazyChucky! thanks for the reply, but I have a concern, following your solution, how could it be printed the session id in the logging?

Comment: Just use the `sessionid.id` variable. One way would be to bind it to an attribute of the `logger` object:
`logger.my_session_id = sessionid.id`
Then from any other script that's imported the logger, you could do
`msg = f'{logger.my_session_id}: a message';
logger.info(msg)`

Comment: Alternatively, have any script that needs it import `sessionid`, then have it access `sessionid.id` when creating the message, like: `msg = f'{sessionid.id}: a message'; logger.info(msg)`

Comment: HI @CrazyChucky, I have moved my solution to Flask and it does support using custom variables in logging. We can use your proceed with the described in https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/logging/#injecting-request-information. All we need to do is set `record.session_id = config.session_id` attribute in **RequestFormatter** and then update the **session_id** during runtime